# Variable Content Query Webpart in Sandbox Solutions

Tags: sandbox-solution, content-query-web-part, site-template

I'm stuck with the following problem.
I have a Sharepoint Sandbox Solutions project. On the main page there's
a list "Artists" with URLs that direct to the proper Artist Page. Those artist pages are created with an event receiver
Example:
Bob Marley - http://intranet.contoso.com/Artists/BobMarley 
Jack White - http://intranet.contoso.com/Artists/JackWhite 
And so on
These artistpages have a document library filled with documents.
On the same main page mentioned above there's also a list with links to Festivals.
Each of these festivals has artists performing on it. For each artist in a Festival, an event receiver creates a specific artist page for that artist under a Festival. 
Example:
Bob Marley on Woodstock - http://intranet.contoso.com/Woodstock/BobMarley 
Jack White on Woodstock - http://intranet.contoso.com/Woodstock/JackWhite 
The **problem** is: I want to use something like a content query or content search webpart to link the docs of http://intranet.contoso.com/BobMarley to http://intranet.contoso.com/Woodstock/BobMarley. But this needs to be done automatically. So in the template of Bob Marley under Woodstock there has to be a webpart that knows it's on the Bob Marley page and can lookup the docs that are in the Bob Marley site in http://intranet.contoso.com/BobMarley.

How can I accomplish this. I have tried to use the ListViewByQuery webpart but this approach didn't worked under Sandbox Solutions. Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PageFieldValue as a filter in a CQWP so when you create your page then set a field value to your artist then in your CQWP you would use:

```
[PageFieldValue:artist]
```

Another possibility to consider is to have a single page that is driven by a parameter rather than create a new page for each artist.

```
http://server/site/artist.aspx?artist=BobMarley
```

You can then have multiple web parts on the page that use the query string value as a filter.  In your CQWP you would use:

```
[PageQueryString:artist]
```